# Нужна ли карта сайта sitemap.xml сегодня?

Tags: html

Нужна ли карта сайта sitemap.xml сегодня для SEO оптимизации, нашёл только противоречивые данные, некоторые говорят что сегодня в ней нет необходимости, а некоторые, что без неё никуда!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixer привёл в пример хорошую статью, но если в двух словах, то sitemap.xml нужен для облегчения работы поисковых роботов по поиску ссылок на сайте. По рекомендациям того же гугла sitemap не требуется для небольших сайтов до 500 страниц т.е. для большенства проектов - личных сайтов, сайтов компаний он не требуется!)

Answer (score 3):

Статья от гугла, когда sitemap нужен, а когда нет.

[тык](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=ru)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/452919)

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать.